# Lambda wont write to mongodb but i can write to it locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm using aws lambdas that I'm deploying via serverless.com to aws, and writing to mongodb using the connection string. This all works when invoking the lambda locally, and I've checked to see that the data I'm writing to it locally comes in as the same format as that I'm writing to the live one, and it is. I have no idea what's wrong, as I'm not getting errors.

```
    "use strict";
    module.exports.addNewMenuItem = async event => {
        var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        const options = {
            socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
            keepAlive: true,
            reconnectTries: 30000,
            useUnifiedTopology: true  , 
            useNewUrlParser: true 
        };
        ;

        console.log(process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING)
        console.log("eb", event.body)
        const { coffee_type, coffee_subtype, business_id } = event.body
        const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING, options);
        await client.connect(clientConnectError => {
            if (clientConnectError) {
                console.log("client connection error", clientConnectError)
            }

            client.db("Coffee2Go").collection("MenuItems").insertOne({ coffee_type, coffee_subtype, business_id }, function (writeError, result) {
                if (writeError) {
                    console.log("db error", writeError)
                }

                console.log("added the new menu item successfully")
            });
        });

        return {
            "body": "menu item added successfully",
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            "statusCode": 200
        };
    };
```

[image: Logs with mongodb connection string blurred]

Comment: By default lambda function are set to 3 seconds timeout, Increase this timeout to 1 minute and check if this is still happening

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your function just take 6.78 ms to finish, this mean the function did not waiting for your query finish, it just returns an object immediate. The function will stop when it hits `return`.

In your local side, Mongodb query still running when you function gets `return`. But it not working on lambda side, when the function stop, it will stop all process.

The main reason is you are mixing `async/await` syntax with `callback` syntax for `MongoClient`.

```
await client.connect(clientConnectError => { // does not make sense
```

As Mongodb [document](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html) , you can use their method as Promises.

```
"use strict";
module.exports.addNewMenuItem = async event => {
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  const options = {
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: 30000,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  };
  ;

  console.log(process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING)
  console.log("eb", event.body)
  const { coffee_type, coffee_subtype, business_id } = event.body
  const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING, options);

  try {
    await client.connect() // return Promise if no callback passed
    await client.db("Coffee2Go").collection("MenuItems").insertOne({ coffee_type, coffee_subtype, business_id })
    console.log("added the new menu item successfully")
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("db error", writeError)
    // As your original logic. The error will not effect to result of the function.
    // But, I think this is not a good flow, you need tell to your client that process get back an error in this case
    return {
      "body": JSON.stringify({
        message: "Insert item error",
        error: err.message
      }),
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      "statusCode": 500 // instead of 200 - success
    };
  }

  return {
    "body": "menu item added successfully",
    "headers": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    "statusCode": 200
  };
};
```